# How to pass data to another page on another domain via POST without specifying it in form?

Tags: jsp, servlets, post

I have a JSP page that has two pieces of data that I need to send to a page on another domain via post when a button is clicked.

My original iteration was just having the two pieces of data in 2 hidden fields and when the user clicked a button it posted those two data and all was good in the universe.

- I showed it to the client and they say that I can't have the data seen in View Source and I can't pass this data via get (even though anyone with a sniffer can grab the POST contents. the client wont listen).
- They also nixed my idea of using GET via sendredirect
- They are also against encrypting it and sending it via GET

Is there an "easy" way to do this with just JSP and possibly Javascript? or if necessary through a servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Just submit the form to a servlet which in turn uses [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) to fire another POST request programmatically. This way your servlet will act as a proxy.

#### See also:

- [How to use `java.net.URLConnection` to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)